# bash: try to find my mistake with test existence of a file

Tags: bash, file, if-statement

I try to find my mistake in my bash script:

open a file with filename (1 by line)

check for each filename if it exist

file position: ~/student_code/data/

my test command works:

```
if test -e ~/student_code/data/john_18.doc; then echo "File exists"; else echo "File doesn't exist"; fi
```

echo file exist

But not my script

```
#!/bin/bash

files=$(grep " john " ../data/listing.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 3)   #find file with john in listing.txt
#echo "$files"  #testing line => OK
path="~/student_code"
for file in $files;
do
        output="${path}${file}"    # concate path
        echo "$output";            
# testing line => 1st output: ~/student_code/data/john_18.doc

        if test -e "${output}";    # test for existence of the file
                then echo "File exists";
        else echo "File doesn't exist"; fi
done
```

output: File doesn't exist for each file

I'm not very confortable with bash, so it may be an idiot mistake.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Thank Cyrus, I didn't know about this checker. Thank for this new tool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` isn't expanded to your home directory inside double quotes.  You are testing for the existence of your file in a directory literally named `~`, which of course does not exist.

You can either omit the quotes:

```
path=~/student_code
```

or use `$HOME` instead of `~`:

```
path="$HOME/student_code"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I use the first one. Work great. The second is not working maybe because I work on a cloud machine (GCP). The first one is more compatible. Thank again! Have a nice day.